# How can I append an object to another object?

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me append an object another object? For example, I have the original object:

```
var object = {
    { product_code: '55993',
      brand: 'Phillips66',
      category: 'LUBES AND GREASES',
      description: 'cuatro cinco seis',
      price: '300.00',
      quantity: '3' 
    }
}
```

and I want to append:

```
    { product_code: '90210',
      brand: 'Phillips66',
      category: 'LUBES AND GREASES',
      description: 'cuatro cinco seis',
      price: '500.00',
      quantity: '5' 
    }
```

So in the end, `object` looks like:

```
object = {
    { product_code: '55993',
      brand: 'Phillips66',
      category: 'LUBES AND GREASES',
      description: 'cuatro cinco seis',
      price: '300.00',
      quantity: '3' 
    },
    { product_code: '90210',
      brand: 'Phillips66',
      category: 'LUBES AND GREASES',
      description: 'cuatro cinco seis',
      price: '500.00',
      quantity: '5' 
    }
}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: `var object = { {key: "value"} }` is not valid JavaScript. Object properties need keys.

Comment: There is no JSON in your question. JSON is a textual notation. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Use Array of objects, you are trying to use object of objects which will get more complex and also your current structure does not support it

Answer (score 14):

You can use ES6 spread operator to append object.

```
object = { ...object, 
...{ product_code: '90210',
      brand: 'Phillips66',
      category: 'LUBES AND GREASES',
      description: 'cuatro cinco seis',
      price: '500.00',
      quantity: '5' 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Your object variable should be an array, not an object:

```
    var object = [
        { product_code: '55993',
          brand: 'Phillips66',
          category: 'LUBES AND GREASES',
          description: 'cuatro cinco seis',
          price: '300.00',
          quantity: '3' 
        }
    ]
```

Then you can add other objects into it:

```
object.push({ product_code: '90210',
      brand: 'Phillips66',
      category: 'LUBES AND GREASES',
      description: 'cuatro cinco seis',
      price: '500.00',
      quantity: '5' 
    });
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of options:

1. Define a property name under which to store the second object, which won't give you a structure like the one you've shown at the end of your question.
2. Use an *array*, which will give you something very nearly like what you have at the end of your question:

   ```
   [
       { product_code: '55993',
         brand: 'Phillips66',
         category: 'LUBES AND GREASES',
         description: 'cuatro cinco seis',
         price: '300.00',
         quantity: '3' 
       },
       { product_code: '90210',
         brand: 'Phillips66',
         category: 'LUBES AND GREASES',
         description: 'cuatro cinco seis',
         price: '500.00',
         quantity: '5' 
       }
   ]
   ```

   Note the `[` and `]` instead of `{` and `}` at the outermost level.

If you have an object:

```
var object1 = {foo: "bar"};
```

and another object:

```
var object2 = {biz: "baz"};
```

Then option #1 looks like this:

```
object1.anyNameHere = object2;
```

...which will give you:

```
{
   foo: "bar",
   anyNameHere: {
       biz: "baz"
   }
}
```

Or option #2:

```
var a = [object1, object2];
```

...which will give you:

```
[
    {
        foo: "bar"
    },
    {
        biz: "baz"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways but the first one is the best way you can retrieve data easily using for loop

```
var object1 = { product_code: '55993',
    brand: 'Phillips66',
    category: 'LUBES AND GREASES',
    description: 'cuatro cinco seis',
    price: '300.00',
    quantity: '3'
};

var object2 ={ product_code: '55993',
    brand: 'Phillips66',
    category: 'LUBES AND GREASES',
    description: 'cuatro cinco seis',
    price: '300.00',
    quantity: '3'
}
```

**1) create one array variable and push all your objects in that array**

```
var myObjectList = [];
myObjectList.push(object1);
myObjectList.push(object2);
```

**2) You can create the objects and assign value to that object**

```
var myObjectList = {object1: object1, object2 : object2};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.assign( object, tail )` or `{ ...object, ...tail }` as described in [1]:

When you want to merge a `var` that is **mutable** `assign` or `...` will look like this:

```
var object = {
      product_code: '55993',
      brand: 'Phillips66',
      category: 'LUBES AND GREASES',
      description: 'cuatro cinco seis',
      price: '300.00',
      quantity: '3' 
};

object = Object.assign( object, { product_code: '90210',
      brand: 'Phillips66',
      category: 'LUBES AND GREASES',
      description: 'cuatro cinco seis',
      price: '500.00',
      quantity: '5' 
    }
);

or

object = { ...object, ...{ product_code: '90210',
      brand: 'Phillips66',
      category: 'LUBES AND GREASES',
      description: 'cuatro cinco seis',
      price: '500.00',
      quantity: '5' 
    }
};
```

If you want to merge two `const` **immutable** object you need to `assign` or `...` to anew object:

```
const object = {
      product_code: '55993',
      brand: 'Phillips66',
      category: 'LUBES AND GREASES',
      description: 'cuatro cinco seis',
      price: '300.00',
      quantity: '3' 
};

const tail = {
      product_code: '90210',
      brand: 'Phillips66',
      category: 'LUBES AND GREASES',
      description: 'cuatro cinco seis',
      price: '500.00',
      quantity: '5' 
};

const result = Object.assign( object, tail );

or

const result = { ...object, ...tail };
```

Note that you can chain `assign` / `...` with more parameters. You can also use that to join `{ {xx} }` objects accordingly (assuming they are valid object already).

This is something I was looking for to extend my datamodels with some base root parameters list but I did not want to use `class` :-)

[1] https://attacomsian.com/blog/javascript-merge-objects

Answer (score 0):

I vote up CaptainAdmin answer, of using spread syntax. Very useful, and good to know it is there. However, in this case, it'd be both more convenient and correct to use something like:

```
var o1 = {
    product_name: "Super One",
};

var o2 = {
    quantity: 50,
};

specializeWith(o1, o2);
```

Where:

```
function specialize_with(o, S) { for (var prop in S) { o[prop] = S[prop]; } }
```

Then your `o1` will be:

```
var o1 = {
    product_name: "Super One",
    quantity: 50,
};
```

Unfortunately, looking closely at the original question, I see that's not what was asked in the first place. The array of objects was needed, not an inheritance or specialization or extension. Still, leaving it here.

See also https://github.com/latitov/OOP_MI_Ct_oPlus_in_JS, the specializeWith() is from there.

Again, please look at https://github.com/latitov/OOP_MI_Ct_oPlus_in_JS.

Answer (score 0):

if your fields is difference:

```
<body>

<p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>

<script>
var primaryValue = {"id": "4"};

var obj = new Object();
obj = Object.assign(primaryValue,obj);
obj['name'] = 'sara';
obj['age'] = '32';

document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = obj['id'] + ", " + obj['name'] + ", " + obj['age'];
</script>

</body>
```

and output is:

```
4, sara, 32
```